# Deriving encryption key from Android pattern

Tags: android, encryption, android-security, ext4

I'm aware that many Android devices have hardware-backed encryption that may add further complexity to the key, but what are the actual steps that are taken to produce a key from a lock pattern? How is the pattern encoded down to a scalar argument passed as input into the process?